# Datagrid focus to selected row

Tags: wpf

I have a simple datagrid with some itemssource. I select a row and go to other control. Every time i focus the grid again using tab, it selects the first row and cell. (It show a black border box on first cell)

I have set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` but not working

I want the previous selected row to get focus.

[image]

Comment: Using Tab key changes the focus to the next element that can receive focus. It does not change selection of the DataGrid. For that to happen you have to write event handler for DataGrid Focused event, for example.

Answer (score 0):

"it selects the first row and cell" no in fact the selection remains as it was but yes when the focus returns to datagrid the focused cell will change to the first cell.
Check if this approach suits you, it's the simplest I came with so far!:

- First, add event handler to cell GotFocus and LostFocus as follows:

  ```
    <DataGrid x:Name="list_1">
       <DataGrid.Columns >
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="30" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="50" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserID" Width="50" Binding="{Binding user_id}"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGrid.CellStyle >
           <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
               <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="cgf"/>
               <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="clf"/>
           </Style>
       </DataGrid.CellStyle>
   </DataGrid>
  ```
- In your code behind, add the following code:

  ```
    Private WithEvents timer1 As New Threading.DispatcherTimer With {.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)}
    Private WithEvents timer2 As New Threading.DispatcherTimer With {.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)}

    Dim LastFocusedCell As DataGridCell
    Dim focus_lost As Boolean

    Sub cgf(sender As object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
         timer1.Stop()
         If focus_lost Then
              focus_lost = False
              If LastFocusedCell IsNot Nothing Then
                   list_1.IsReadOnly = True
                   LastFocusedCell.Focus()
                   timer2.Start()
              Else
                   LastFocusedCell = sender
              End If
         Else
              LastFocusedCell = sender
         End If
    End Sub

    Sub clf(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
         timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
         timer1.Stop()
         focus_lost = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer2.Tick
         timer2.stop()
         list_1.IsReadOnly = False
    End Sub
  ```

I don't think it's the best approach but it worked fine for me.